# Interview problem - two light bulbs and a 100-story building

Tags: interviewing

I was looking at [this](http://www.businessinsider.in/29-of-the-toughest-interview-questions-youll-have-to-answer-to-work-at-Facebook/You-have-two-light-bulbs-and-a-100-story-building-You-want-to-find-the-floor-at-which-the-bulbs-will-break-when-dropped-Find-the-floor-using-the-least-number-of-drops-Software-Engineer-candidate/slideshow/49245444.cms) problem.

> You have two light bulbs and a 100-story building. You want to find the floor at which the bulbs will break when dropped. Find the floor using the least number of drops.

- What is the right way to answer this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a brain teaser; not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31525/discussion-on-question-by-xameeramir-interview-problem-two-light-bulbs-and-a-1).

Comment: I know I saw this question on a different stack exchange, but I cannot find it now.  This is a link to someone who has solved the problem: https://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/2-light-bulbs-and-a-100-story-building-solution/

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this one on Puzzling.SE.

Comment: If you drop them indoors, most bulbs will beak no matter what floor you're on. If out a window, you might want to look at the building -- it may have set-back floore that create intermediate surfaces before hitting street level. But the best answer, if not forbidden, is zero drops: Pick up the phone, call the manufacturer, and ask what their impact design spec is for this bulb. I'd want to see candidates not jump to a conclusion without defining the real problem... if I asked this sort of question, which I don't.

Comment: Drop them out of the second floor. If they don't break, go work for the company that makes those bulbs because they're pretty awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary goal of this question is to test analytic thinking and problem solving skills. The question itself is fairly trivial, but the path to the solution (if you haven't already seen the question) tells an interviewer much more about the candidate than the actual answer would.

First, as an example, all of the comments/answers that involve rhetoric and semantics would immediately get you disqualified from the position. The question is not about semantics. It is a very simple and straight-forward question with a simple premise. Identifying the rules of the system without needing to be "hand-held" would show at least to a degree independence of thinking. If there are assumptions for which you're unsure, asking to clarify is always the best policy, but going overboard with it leads to the second thing.

If you try to deconstruct the problem aggressively (what is a floor? how is the bulb dropped? what color are the bulbs?) indicates to the interviewer that you are unable to distinguish between important factors and unimportant factors. You may even be judged to have a tendency to over-complicate problems. If this trivial problem provides you with such complications, what will a real-world business problem do to you?

Thirdly, it provides you the forum to show how to "prove" your solution. Whether you're right or wrong, if you show a viable process and a viable method for arriving at it, that is going to be valuable to an interviewer.

Finally, if the position calls for mathematical or logical reasoning skills (software, financial analysis, manufacturing planning) then it shows that you can take the core of the problem, reduce it to a set of variables and find a solution given the prime criteria.

If you've seen this question before and "know" the answer, you should simply identify that and then walk them through the solution as you understand it.

Comment: Sure there are a lot of possible insights to this question but reality is if the interviewer has to rely on search engines to find interview questions then how would you be so certain that the same person would reliably interpret your answer? As you said you can over complicate this question and even more so an interviewer can over interpret the answer. It works on both sides of the coin and as such anyone - interviewers or interviewees - should avoid these kind of questions.

Comment: @Dan: It's not a question I use personally, and I wouldn't presume to tell anyone else what they should or should not use to make their determinations. I am neither advocating for nor against this question, I am simply providing legitimate insight into the potential value of the question should it be presented to someone who is unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @dan So now the interviewer cannot interpret answer.  There is no interpretation - there is a correct mathematical answer that is easy to explain and prove.  I agree you should avoid these kind of questions.

Comment: Perhaps it is a question about semantics and think outside the box

Comment: My answer to these questions is to pull out my phone and search for the solution. No decent Engineer would ever start solving an unfamiliar problem without looking at what has already been done. Maybe recent graduates would solve a pop quiz in an interview, but if I asked a similar question to someone with experience and didn't get any push back, that would be a red flag to me. I would expect that candidate to spend time re-inventing the wheel and chasing wild geese because they don't stop to think about why they are doing something. The goal of an interview is not to solve puzzles.

Answer (score 4):

This is a cool question. Clearly you assume the bulbs are identical and drops are identical and they want to find the minimum floor.  State that as an assumption.

It is a destructive test so you cannot do interval halving.  If the first breaks on floor 50 and you half the interval to 25 and the second breaks then all you know is that it breaks some where on 1-24.  If you start on floor one you can do it will 1 bulb and 100 drops.

I see Dan posted a link to the answer so I won't repeat it.

I am a mathematician and software developer and I deal with a lot of analytics.  I look at stuff from the two egg/bulb perspective a lot.  It took me about 20 minutes to solve that that first time and in an interview would be harder.  That is not an interview I would walk away from.  They are looking for people that think like me. And I have a software program where I use that algorithm to minimize the number of comparisons I need to make.

Comment: This is a great solution, but it assumes that an unbroken bulb that has been dropped 90 times from progressively higher heights has the same durability as a brand new bulb.  A mechanical engineer might have a problem with that assumption.

Comment: If the stated question is which floor the bulbs (plural) will break then it implies bulbs are equal and drops are equal (to me).

Comment: The answer is "the lobby" and you get to keep both bulbs and move on to the next question. There are far better-posed questions to ask if you just want the candidate to show he understands a freaking binary search.

Comment: @Frisbee - Where do you get the equal bit?

Comment: @EdHeal Logic.  Bulbs - plural.   Context.   You really think the question is about two dissimilar bulbs?   What about wind?  Will the bulb possibly land on grass rather than a sidewalk?   You think this about actual bulbs and an actual building?

Comment: It could be a Daffodil bulb or the part at the end of the thermometer.  There is two bulbs and that is thinking outside the box. Both can be light (colour or weight for example). Floor can mean the lowest point....

Comment: @EdHeal Could mean a lot of things.  So you still think it is about an actual bulb and an actual building?  Pretty sure you don't get the job.

Comment: @teego1967 So it is not freaking binary search.   The question is not what it is not.  The question is how to solve it - can you?

Comment: @Frisbee, honestly, the binary search is the first thing I would consider, I see now that it is not the best choice, but certainly not the worst. I am irritated by the casusal description of a very weird situation quite deliberately meant to throw people off. I think I can solve it but it would take too long in an interview situation.

Comment: @teego1967 Fails is worst.  The description is neither casual nor weird to those that get it.  For people that do encryption algorithms, network path, fraud detection, spam detection ... this is a relevant.  Look at the algorithms for bitcoin, Levenshtein distance, or Naive bayes  and this is a walk in the park.

Comment: @teego1967 it's not the worst but it's O(the worst). If you want to condescend this question you might want to avoid showing off how easy it is.

Answer (score 3):

> You have two light bulbs and a 100-story building. You want to find the floor at which the bulbs will break when dropped. Find the floor using the least number of drops.

This question sounds silly because how do you drop the bulbs? Out the window or do you simply walk to floor X and drop it to test if gravity is somehow different? This question seems flawed in how one can think of a solution.

The way I would have answered it is you start at floor 50 and drop one bulb. If it breaks. go to floor 25 and drop the second. If it breaks you know you don't have to climb more than 25 floors to break the bulb.

There is an thought out answer here: https://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/2-light-bulbs-and-a-100-story-building-solution/

However, I agree with others that you should simply get up and walk out from this interview. Main reason is that when you search for google for this question, it pops up. It shows me two things: 1) They can't think of interview questions to ask in order to determine your skill set, and 2) It's probably a bad place if they have to think of clever ways to ask a simple question which is, "How do you determine the best way to solve a basic problem such as [insert our industry's common problem]?"

Comment: That post doesn't seem to know what a binary search is.

Comment: Yeah this isn't a binary search as you only have two potential misses, while a binary search requires...log2(n)+1 attempts in the worst case (plus one successful attempted. Meaning we need at least 8 bulbs. This is an efficiency question, and a ridiculous one for anyone but a very niche set of roles. A regular software engineer or similar doesn't need to perform a search on 100 items with only two failures...ever

Comment: If the first bulb breaks from the 50th floor, and the second breaks from the 25th floor, you can't find which floor from the 1st to the 25th is the one where the bulb breaks.

Comment: I think you'd be surprised how many people still can't explain the answer well even if they googled it previously.  Not to mention, these questions are best used as starting points.  If two bulbs is too easy, what about three?

Answer (score 0):

> You have two light bulbs and a 100-story building. You want to find
>   the floor at which the bulbs will break when dropped. Find the floor
>   using the least number of drops.

Notice the details missing in the question and have the conversation to gain the other requirements that are likely here:

1. "The floor" that is likely "the lowest floor" as otherwise we could just use the highest floor and be done with the problem.
2. What kind of proof is wanted to know that a bulb would break if dropped from floor X? If there are trials to do then there are at most 2 drops that could be done unless there are others available.
3. Is the drop just a simple release or could one throw the bulb down into the ground? There are various factors here that could be worth noting.
4. Should we have "Warning: Bulbs being dropped" signs out front when we do test the drops?

---

The question is designed to be a fishing expedition to my mind. What kind of assumptions would one make? How does one phrase the questions on the undisclosed requirements here?

I can see the idea of this being similar to someone that has an idea to put an enhancement into a system or application but doesn't quite get what kind of impact could this have on others.

Comment: Correct, I had similar thought in my answer as well. This question is flawed because it is asking for a specific solution for an unspecific problem. That could be why it is asked but reality is it is a rather silly question that should probably remain in academic classrooms rather than workplaces.

Comment: "If there are trials to do then there are at most 2 drops that could be done unless there are others available." That part is incorrect. You're assuming the bulb is going to beak each time you drop it. If you're afraid of running out of bulbs, then just start from the bottom and work your way up.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, or the bulb has to be left as evidence after each drop. Remember that no protocols were given which could be part of what is to be discussed as there may be rules to discover only when one asks about them. Look up the card game "Mau" for an example a game where part of the point is figuring out the rules.

Comment: Agreed, my first thought was to drop it from 100th floor where i can be sure it breaks without much calculating and that is probably what i would have said at an interview.

Answer (score -3):

The question isn't stupid - if they ask you to think out the whole process as they want to see how you approach the problem. Mostly from an optimization standpoint.

But ya, think about it from an optimization standpoint.  Think out-loud, whiteboard, whatever and keep thinking "can I do this better?"

Comment: The answer is floor 10.  If it doesn't break that's 9 more to check at most (10) total.  If it doesn't you go up to 20 and repeat.  This is the optimal solution

Comment: Yes there are a lot of ways to test it but I disagree that it would assets optimization skills since it is asking for a specific answer to a unspecific question. It leaves out many key things such as exactly what are you attempting to find/solve. Note it doesn't ask what is the minimum floor in which a bulb will break.